# WPF. Application.Startup вылетает ошибка при запуске

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Понадобилось использовать параметры при запуске приложения. В Winforms с этим полный порядок. Наткнулся на статью в MSDN

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.110).aspx

И вроде сделал как там указано, а на выходе получаю unhandled
[image: Срабатывает после вызова <code>main.Show();</code>]

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {        
        public MainWindow(string args)
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
    }
```

Comment: может `string[] args` нужно?

Comment: не, с типами все норм                                                                       
 void App_Startup(object sender,  StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow main = new MainWindow(e.Args[0]);            
            main.Show();            
        }

Comment: Базовый класс Window может накладывать "свои" правила игры. Попробуйте указать  `public MainWindow(string args) :base()`. В вашем примере MainWindow без аргументов, попробуйте без аргументов вызвать.

Comment: Не помогло. Самое интересное, что аргументы передаются, все норм. Только с чего XamlParseException? Это уже MainWindow.xaml выеживается. А откуда inner непонятно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, окну все-таки нужен конструктор по умолчанию. Однако, аргументы командной строки можно получить через [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Да, а разбор командной строки — вовсе не задание окна.

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное на этом и остановлюсь. Но ради интереса надо будет разобраться чем тот вариант не вариант

Comment: Можно просто вызвать конструктор по умолчанию как базовый конструктор -
public MainWindow()
{
            InitializeComponent();            
}
 public MainWindow(string args):this()
        {
//разбор аргумента
        }

Comment: @Rans: Это ограничение UI-контролов, использующихся в XAML. Они **должны** содержать конструктор без параметров. Документация: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379(v=vs.110).aspx